# Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.DateTime'. Error while trying to get data from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on a project that uses SQL Server. And I'm trying to get data from the `Randevular` table. But when I run the linq code, it doesn't return any data. I get an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.DateTime'

Here is my `Randevu` model class:

```
public class Randevu
{
    [Key]
    public int RandevuID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime RandevuDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime RandevuTime {  get; set; }
}
```

And here is the migration model snapshot for the `Randevular` table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("webProgProje.Models.Randevu", b =>
    {
        b.Property<int>("RandevuID")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasColumnType("int");

        SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("RandevuID"));

        b.Property<DateTime>("RandevuDate")
            .HasColumnType("datetime2"); //NOTE: i changed "datetime2" to "date" BEFORE applying to database

        b.Property<DateTime>("RandevuTime") 
            .HasColumnType("datetime2"); //NOTE: i changed "datetime2" to "time" BEFORE applying to database

        b.HasKey("RandevuID");

        b.ToTable("Randevular");
    });
```

And finally, here is the `migration.cs` file:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Randevular",
    columns: table => new
    {
        RandevuID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        RandevuDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false), //NOTE: i changed "datetime2" to "date"
        RandevuTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false), //NOTE: i changed "datetime2" to "time"
});
```

I just want to list all of the `Randevu`'s stored in database but I got stuck in this strange problem.

I tried changing "DateTime" to "TimeSpan" in Randevu `model` and run it and the same error occurred again. But this time it was:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.TimeSpan'

I also tried changing all of DateTime's to TimeSpan in `migration.cs` file and snapshot BEFORE applying to database but same issue persists.

Comment: You state "when I run the linq code". Is this occurring when you run the migration or when you execute application code against the resulting database? What linq code is throwing the error?

Comment: "var r=db.Randevular.OrderBy(x=>x.RandevuID);" this linq code when i run website. I must add that, .Count() works perfectly fine. The issue is on date and time colons.

Comment: Your English is infinitely better than my Turkish. Google translate translates "Randevu" as "Meeting" or "Appointment" and "Randevular" as "Appointments'. So is it correct to assume that `db.Randevular` is a `DbSet<Randevu>`? Since the `Randevu` class has two `DateTime` columns and presumably, the corresponding database table has equivalent `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` column, I see nothing that would involve a `TimeSpan` conversiuon. ...

Comment: ... So, now it is time to look into that which we do not see. First, make absolute sure your migrations and application are referencing the same database. Next, look at any configuration files like EDMX (does EF Core still use that) or any other middleware or configuration files that might themselves have out-of-date column/property definitions. Also, look for any triggers r interceptors that might be running under the covers. Just throwing out ideas.

Comment: Yes, "Randevu"  means "Appointment" and "db.Randevular" is a "DbSet<Randevu>".

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are referencing the same database. Now I'll take a look at those files you have mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Everything explained in this link:

> https://erikej.github.io/efcore/sqlserver/2023/09/03/efcore-dateonly-timeonly.html

Here is the things I've done to solve this problem.

I could not run the console command but I found a way for it too. In Visual Studio, go :

> Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for
> Solution...

from there, click **Browse** tab and search for :

> ErikEJ.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.DateOnlyTimeOnly

Now, select your project in opened window and install latest stable version.

I changed my `Randevu` model class from

```
public class Randevu
{
    [Key]
    public int RandevuID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime RandevuDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime RandevuTime {  get; set; }
}
```

To :

```
public class Randevu
{
    [Key]
    public int RandevuID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateOnly RandevuDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TimeOnly RandevuTime {  get; set; }
}
```

Then changed `OnConfiguring` method in `DbContext` model class from :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVER02;Database=master;
          Trusted_Connection=True;
          TrustServerCertificate=True");
    }
```

To :

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVER02;Database=master;
          Trusted_Connection=True;
          TrustServerCertificate=True",x=>x.UseDateOnlyTimeOnly());
    }
```

After migration,

Migration model snapshot for `Randevular` table went from this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity("webProgProje.Models.Randevu", b =>
    {
        b.Property<int>("RandevuID")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasColumnType("int");

        SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("RandevuID"));

        b.Property<DateTime>("RandevuDate")
            .HasColumnType("datetime2"); 

        b.Property<DateTime>("RandevuTime") 
            .HasColumnType("datetime2"); 

        b.HasKey("RandevuID");

        b.ToTable("Randevular");
    });
```

To this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity("webProgProje.Models.Randevu", b =>
    {
        b.Property<int>("RandevuID")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasColumnType("int");

        SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("RandevuID"));

        b.Property<DateOnly>("RandevuDate")
            .HasColumnType("date"); 

        b.Property<TimeOnly>("RandevuTime") 
            .HasColumnType("time"); 

        b.HasKey("RandevuID");

        b.ToTable("Randevular");
    });
```

So the `migration.cs` file went from this :

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Randevular",
    columns: table => new
    {
        RandevuID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        RandevuDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
        RandevuTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
});
```

To this :

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Randevular",
    columns: table => new
    {
        RandevuID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        RandevuDate = table.Column<DateOnly>(type: "date", nullable: false), 
        RandevuTime = table.Column<TimeOnly>(type: "time", nullable: false), 
});
```

After all of these steps, it works fine. I'm not getting any error while requesting data from server.

Results,

Stored data is :

> RandevuDate: 12.12.2023, RandevuTime: 10:00:00)

Values I get from database,

Date value:

> Year 2023 Month 12 Day 12 DayOfWeek Tuesday DayOfYear 346 DayNumber
> 738865

Time value:

> Hour 10 Minute 0 Second 0 Millisecond 0 Ticks 360000000000

I think we can manipulate the output string to the format we want to show from now on.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
TimeSpan timeSpanValue = (TimeSpan)reader["timeSpanColumn"];
DateTime dateTimeValue = DateTime.Now.Add(timeSpanValue);
```

Comment: im a bit confused. Where should i put this lines?